# Segmentation fault (core dumped) for Struct Pointer Member

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Please anyone can tell me what mistake i'm doing in the code.

```
struct aluArgu{
    int noOfArgu;
    char** const argv;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{ 
    struct aluArgu* aluArgs = malloc(sizeof(struct aluArgu)+argc*sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
            aluArgs->argv[i] = malloc(strlen(argv[i])+1);
            strcpy(aluArgs->argv[i],argv[i]);
    }
    aluArgs->noOfArgu = argc;
}
```

When i run the code like this i'm getting the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

```
gcc filecode.c -o mycprogram

./mycprogram 3 + 4
```

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `argv` member of `struct aluArgu` is not an array, it is a pointer.  That pointer was never assigned a value, so writing to `aluArgs->argv[i]` dereferenced an uninitialized pointer which invokes [undefined beahvior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

It seems what you want here, based on how you allocate the struct, is a **flexible array member**:

```
struct aluArgu{
    int noOfArgu;
    char *argv[];
};
```

Now you have an actual array with space allocated for `argc` items.